auth.currentUser = null, NextJS 14 AuthJS v5 Firebase Auth
I'm facing a problem for almost 2 days. I want to make a change-password page with Firebase Auth
change-password/page.tsx
"use client";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { auth } from "@/firebase";
import { useSession } from "next-auth/react";
import {
  reauthenticateWithCredential,
  EmailAuthProvider,
  updatePassword,
  onAuthStateChanged,
  getAuth,
} from "firebase/auth";
import { User } from "next-auth";

const ChangePass = () => {
  const [oldPassword, setOldPassword] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [confirmPassword, setConfirmPassword] = useState("");
  const [passMatch, setPassMatch] = useState(true);

  async function changePassword(currentPassword: string, newPassword: string) {
    const user = auth.currentUser;

    if (!user) {
      throw new Error("No user logged in");
    } else {
      if (!passMatch) {
        return console.log("Passwords don't match");
      }

      const credential = EmailAuthProvider.credential(
        user.email!,
        currentPassword
      );
        reauthenticateWithCredential(user, credential);
        updatePassword(user, newPassword);
  }
}

  // Handle form submission
  const handleSubmit = async (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      await changePassword(oldPassword, password);
      alert("Password changed successfully!");
    } catch (error: any) {
      alert(error.message);
    }
  };

  return (
    <main className="lg:w-10/12 lg:mx-auto p-8 h-[90vh] flex justify-center items-center">
      <form
        onSubmit={handleSubmit}
        className="flex flex-col bg-white p-10 py-10 rounded-xl shadow-xl lg:items-center justify-center lg:w-fit"
      >
        <label className="text-lg font-normal mb-1">Current Password : </label>
        <input
          name="oldPassword"
          type="password"
          className="bg-transparent placeholder:text-gray-300 border-2 bg-white border-red-400 rounded-2xl py-0.5 px-2 w-80 outline-none"
          placeholder="Enter old password"
          value={oldPassword}
          onChange={(e) => setOldPassword(e.target.value)}
        />
        <label className="text-lg font-semibold mb-1 mt-5">Password</label>
        <input
          name="password"
          type="password"
          className="bg-transparent border-2 placeholder:text-gray-300 bg-white border-red-600 rounded-2xl py-0.5 px-2 w-80 outline-none"
          placeholder="Enter new password"
          value={password}
          onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
        />
        <label className="text-lg  font-semibold mt-5 mb-1">
          Confirm password
        </label>
        <input
          name="confirmPassword"
          type="password"
          className="bg-transparent border-2 placeholder:text-gray-300 bg-white border-red-600 rounded-2xl py-0.5 px-2 w-80 outline-none"
          placeholder="Confirm new password"
          value={confirmPassword}
          onChange={(e) => setConfirmPassword(e.target.value)}
        />
        {!passMatch && (
          <p className="text-xs pl-2 mt-1 text-red-400 text-left">
            Passwords don&apos;t match
          </p>
        )}
        <button
          type="submit"
          className="bg-gradient-to-b from-red-800 to-red-600 text-gray-100 w-fit rounded-lg mx-auto py-2 px-4 font-semibold mt-8"
          disabled={!passMatch || !password || !oldPassword}
        >
          Change password
        </button>
      </form>
    </main>
  );
};

export default ChangePass;

I searched that i need auth.currentUser, but for some reason it is null and i can't updatePassword
I tried to make use of onAuthStateChanged but unfortunately it didn't help me.
What I found out about this problem is that if I log in from the /signin page and then I was redirected to / and in the main page.tsx i did
const session = await auth(); const user = authFirebase.currentUser; console.log(user);
and it showed me the user but only after i logged in, and then when i changed the link to /change-password it became null.
Session is working but currentUser no.
Any thoughts on this?
Thanks and best wishes :*

You should definitely use onAuthStateChanged.  If it didn't help, then you weren't using it correctly.  currentUser is null when the auth state of the user isn't yet known, which is always the case when the page first loads.  The user doesn't actually become signed in until some time later.  Read: Why is my currentUser == null?
